# How do I parse data from any TreeItem when rightclicking it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on an extension and have some trouble implementing command for right clicking elements from my TreeView (namely HomeItem elements).

I have implemented the command to simply click on an element and reveal it's location like this:

in home.ts (for treeView):

```
this.command = {
    title: "Reveal Method",
    command: "extension-home.click",
    arguments: [line,character]
};
```

in extension.ts:

```
let clickEvent = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension-home.click', (line: number, character: number) => {
     lineA = line;
     characterA = character;
     isParent = false;

     // execute vscode commandto jump to location at (line,character)
     const functionPosition = new vscode.Position(line,character);
     vscode.window.activeTextEditor!.selections = [new vscode.Selection(functionPosition, functionPosition)];
     vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup");
});
```

Now I got some functionality to execute a command when right clicking and choosing from the context list, with this:

```
let highlightEvent = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension-home.rightClick', () => {
     if (isParent === false) {
         console.log('Line: ' + lineA + ', Position: ' + characterA);
     } else {
         console.log(allFunctionsLIST);
     }
});
```

The logs created in highlightEvent work, but because in clickEvent the location for some item/method is parsed and the local variable (lineA) is saved with the parsed values, I can only access the data from the last clicked item

This is my main problem, when right clicking some item and selecting from the context menu, it displays what I want, but from the last clicked item.
Is is possible to 'left click' the item when it is rightclicked so the data for the right clicked item get parsed and not the last left clicked?

Comment: check the arguments to your `extension-home.rightClick` function

Comment: @rioV8 i already had a version where highlightevent takes arguments, but it seems I can't provide multiple commands to one treeItem in the constructor. I provide line & character in the provider and use this.command = { command: ".....} so I can only use one. Isn't it possible to set multiple command for treeItems?

Comment: you can add as many menu commands as you like, see the contribution points doc page

Comment: @rioV8 I know, the command itself and anything else works perfectly, when I click on any treeItem it's location gets parsed and so on. The only problem is that when I rightclick any treeItem and click on the context menu command, it works with the data of the last treeItem I simply clicked on.
But I want the data of the right clicked treeItem to be send as arguments, but I can only set one command in the constructor of my treeItem because of `this.command = ...`

Comment: what I think of is providing multiple entries like this:
`this.command = { title: "Reveal Method", command: "extension-home.click", arguments: [line,character] },   {  title: "Highlight Method", command: "extension.rightClick", arguments: [line,character] };`
but the second command is never sent / can't be used

Comment: So you want 2 commands executed when you click on your context menu option?  Any reason one command can't do both things?